# if background image is not there, then show anothe background in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am using Angularjs

I having this code

```
<span variant="2" class="thumb" style="background-image: url(1UP-Cook/31UP-Cook-articleLarge.jpg'); width: 270px; height: 270px;"></span>
```

Now i want if my background src is not present

I want to show a default image on it..

Any idea, how to do this

Thanks

Comment: check if the image exists on the server side. If not then show the default image.

Answer (score 0):

Try it, set your default image as .thumb_wrapper background.

```css
span {display:block}
```

```html
<span class="thumb_wrapper" style="background-color:red">
    <span 
        class="thumb" 
        style="background-image: url('1UP-Cook/31UP-Cook-articleLarge.jpg'); width: 270px; height: 270px;"
    >
        lorem
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: if i have 1000 image. will it add  background 1000 times ?